# Complex video before starting need a basic simple test

Tags: c, gstreamer

In my Fedora 12, when I run this for just a test, it shows a window but then it shows nothing like its frozen. And, it keeps my terminal image instead of video source.

```
$ gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src ! xvimagesink
```

or

```
$ gst-launch-0.10 autovideosrc ! autovideosink
```

How to do a test loopback, not having my screen shot inside the popup window?

Comment: Please let me know if someone know for this answer. This just worked for me, but main question still remain open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$ gst-launch videotestsrc ! ffmpegcolorspace ! ximagesink
```

Which means, I have colorspace problem while using autovideosink. Any experts tips, would be appreciated.

Thanks